# How to change /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log timestamp

Tags: lightdm, logs

Is there a way to change the timestamp format for /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log ? 
I have lines like this

```
[+391362.52s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+391362.52s] DEBUG: Session pid=19196: Exited with return value 0
```

And I would like to 
have something like:

```
 Aug 21 00:25:01 DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
 Aug 21 00:25:01 DEBUG: Session pid=19196: Exited with return value 0
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem I see if I'm not wrong, is that +391362.52s is not a date, but the amount of seconds since you turned your computer on.

Comment: Yes, it is a relative time. The lightdm process has lightdm.log in its opened files. It seems that it logs directly instead of using syslog.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a time format of the type you want by piping the lightdm log-file to systemd journal. Here is an adapted version of a solution taken from a [blog post](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/logfiles-to-systemd-journal.html) by Daniel Aleksandersen. Another discussion of the same idea can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347573/forward-logs-from-file-to-journald). I tried it with Raspbian and lightdm and it worked like a charm.

Modify the existing lightdm.service file like this, for example:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service

[Unit]
Description=Light Display Manager
Documentation=man:lightdm(1)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
# temporary safety check until all DMs are converted to correct
# display-manager.service symlink handling
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ]'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm
Restart=always
BusName=org.freedesktop.DisplayManager

# /etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service.d/pipelog.conf

[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'tail -n 20 "/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log" | systemd-cat -t "lightdm" '
```

Then, once you updated the system (for example by rebooting) the lightdm log entries are accessible via the `journalctl` command. Try `journalctl -t lightdm`, for instance, and you get the output with both the relative time timestamps and the absolute local time.